# How do you remove/delete a column in a custom list that you added from existing site columns?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom list, and I've added a 'Page Image' field by clicking on the 'Add from existing site columns' link on the Settings page for the list. I would now like to remove the field, but clicking on the field name on the Settings page yields no 'Delete' functionality.

How do you remove fields from a custom list in SharePoint that have been added via the 'Add from existing site columns' menu item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Page Image" is a special kind of SharePoint field defined as **Sealed**. This means it cannot be removed from the UI once added. However it can be removed programmatically:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["CustomTest"];
SPField f = list.Fields["Page Image"];
f.Sealed = false;
f.Update();
list.Fields["Page Image"].Delete();
```

For reference, the field is defined in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PublishingResources\PublishingColumns.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides being Sealed, a field can be read-only, hidden and etc. All these factors might prevent the field from deletion. The more suitable method to delete a list field is the following one:

```
public static bool RemoveField(SPField spField)
{
    if (spField == null)
    {
        WriteErrorToLog("spField is null! Please, provide a valid one");
        return false;
    }
 
    bool res = false;
    try
    {
        // check if it's a ReadOnly field.
        // if so, reset it
        if (spField.ReadOnlyField)
        {
            spField.ReadOnlyField = false;
            spField.Update();
        }
 
        // check if it's a Hidden field.
        // if so, reset it
        if (spField.Hidden)
        {
            spField.Hidden = false;
            spField.Update();
        }
 
        // check if the AllowDeletion property is set to false.
        // if so, reset it to true
        if (spField.AllowDeletion == null || !spField.AllowDeletion.Value)
        {
            spField.AllowDeletion = true;
            spField.Update();
        }
 
        // If the AllowDeletion property is set,
        // the Sealed property seems not to be examined at all.
        // So the following piece of code is commented.
        /*if(spField.Sealed)
        {
            spField.Sealed = false;
            spField.Update();
        }*/
 
        // If the AllowDeletion property is set,
        // the FromBaseType property seems not to be examined at all.
        // So the following piece of code is commented.
        /*if(spField.FromBaseType)
        {
            spField.FromBaseType = false;
            spField.Update();
        }*/
 
        // finally, remove the field
        spField.Delete();
        spField.ParentList.Update();
 
        res = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteErrorToLog(ex.Message);
    }
 
    return res;
}
 
public static bool RemoveField(SPList spList, string displayNameOrInternalNameOrStaticName)
{
    SPField spField = GetFieldByName(spList, displayNameOrInternalNameOrStaticName);
    if(spField == null)
    {
        WriteErrorToLog(string.Format("Couldn't find field {0}!", displayNameOrInternalNameOrStaticName));
        return false;
    }
 
    return RemoveField(spField);
}
 
public static void WriteErrorToLog(string errorMsg)
{
    // write error into log
}
```

Read the full [article on my blog](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/07/sharepoint-how-to-delete-a-list-fieldcolumn-programmatically/), to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to "Advanced Settings" within the settings page for your document library.
2. In the radio field "Allow management of content types", click "Yes" and go back to the document library settings
3. Under a new section called "Content Types," click "Document"
4. Click the field you wish to remove; and you should see a "Remove" Button.

Comment: I followed your instructions up until step 3 - it's a custom list, not a Document Library, so I see 'Item' as the only thing listed under 'Content Types', not 'Document'. Clicking on Item yields the list of fields as expected though. When I click on the field I want to remove, however, the only options are 'Required', 'Optional' and 'Hidden' - there's no 'Remove' button. Unfortunately 'Hidden' is not sufficient for my purposes. Any other ideas?

Comment: The only other option I could think of would be to use the object model to get at the content type and pull the extra field off programatically.